# How to get the id of the question or answer linked to a specific badge award?

Tags: stackexchange-api, dataexplorer

I can get the badge id for a specific user, for [example query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1073915):

```
Select *
From Badges
Where UserId = 10907521
```

Example badge id from result

> 30884218

But, how is it possible to get the associated question or answer id (if applicable) for every badge awarded to a user?
For those badges which are not related to a Q&A, we could expect an "NA".

Comment: This question probably belongs on [meta] more than here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Badge awards and posts are not linked in SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede); that information is not available in the Data Explorer.

You could get it from the API, though it ain't pretty.
Reference the:

- [`Usage of /users/{ids}/timeline` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/timeline-on-users)
- and the shorthand [`/me/timeline` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-timeline) (which requires OAuth)

For example, fetching:

[/users/10907521/timeline?pagesize=100&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/timeline-on-users#pagesize=100&ids=10907521&filter=!9Z(-x-d4A&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

returns results like:

```
{
  "badge_id": 10,
  "post_id": 54438094,
  "user_id": 10907521,
  "timeline_type": "badge",
  "post_type": "question",
  "creation_date": 1548848111,
  "detail": "Scholar",
  "title": "Execute a command and save the results into a df from a loop"
}
```

once you filter/search for `badge_id` in the results